# Spring AOP Proxy for java.security.KeyStore

Tags: java, spring, aop, keystore, cglib

I'm wondering is there any way to make a Spring AOP Proxy for the `java.security.KeyStore`, there are few obstacles here:

- KeyStore does not have default constructor
- All methods of KeyStore are **final**

I know that it is impossible to make a Spring AOP Proxy with the above constraints, but anyway I need to somehow count the method invocations of the KeyStore in the application. Could anybody suggest some way to bypass the Spring AOP constraints or another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the calling code - and hopefully you do because it is your own application you are talking about - and are willing to use full AspectJ (which does not need any proxies) instead of Spring-AOP, you cann use a `call()` pointcut instead of being limited to Spring-AOP's `execution()` pointcut. The pointcut would look something like this (untested, hacked from memory):

```java
@Pointcut("call(* java.security.KeyStore.*(..))")
```

If you want to extend the pointcut to subclasses, add a `+` after the class name:

```java
@Pointcut("call(* java.security.KeyStore+.*(..))")
```

You can even intercept constructor calls if they come from code you can weave into:

```java
@Pointcut("call(java.security.KeyStore+.new(..))")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it could be a solution. One more question - is that possible to intercept the calls to specific instance of the KeyStore? I have a few, but interested in only one

Comment: Possibly. I would need more insight into your code for being able to answer that question.